# Prevent Xcode from trying to open large files

Tags: xcode

I have an xcode-project, that contains large json-files inside a resource folder.
From time to time I'm interacting with them, for example when I need to rename or delete something. It occasionally happens - yes I'm kinda clumsy - that I double-click on these files, causing Xcode to try to open these files with 10MB or more, inside an editor. Xcode freezes then and I need to kill the process and restart xcode, which is kind of unhealthy I suppose.

So.. does anybody know a way to stop Xcode from trying to opening such a file, or for example to set a max file size for files Xcode is allowed to open, or some other workaround.

Comment: No, you can't. Xcode is shitty. You can just rename it in cmd, then delete and relink this file to your project.

Comment: this bug still persists in latest version 2021

Comment: still in 2022 . .

Comment: still in November 2022 :(

Comment: Xcode 14 - freezes still exist, but I was able to close the tab which was preparing a large file's layout. Kind of a solution.